# Is there any difference between (cond && value || default_value) and (cond ? value : default_value) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

It seems the two expressions generate the same result.  Is there any difference between them?

Comment: FWIW the second operator is called ternary.

Comment: @cricket_007—ECMA-262 calls it the [*Conditional Operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-conditional-operator), it's **a** ternary operator. ;-)

Comment: It seems that the condition in the ternary operation is incomplete. For fair comparisons of the 2 expressions the second expression should be `cond && value ?value : default_value `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `cond` condition is truthy, but your `value` is not, the first expression will go to the `default_value`, whereas your second expression will give `value` as soon as `cond` is truthy, whatever the actual `value`.

Example:

```js
var cond = true,
    value = false,
    default_value = "whatever";

cond && value || default_value; // gives "whatever"
cond ? value : default_value; // gives `false`

value = "truthy";
cond && value || default_value; // gives "truthy"
cond ? value : default_value; // gives "truthy"

value = null; // or `undefined`, or "" (empty string), or any falsy value.
cond && value || default_value; // gives "whatever"
cond ? value : default_value; // gives `null` (or `undefined`, or "")
// or whatever is in `value`
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/artxvLab/

Comment: Actually you are right, only if  "value" is false, it make difference.In my condition, "value" is a String, an Object or null.So except what you have mentioned, the two expressions are totally equal?

Comment: please delete the `( ... )` at `(cond && value)`. they are not necessary.

Comment: @VincentChen I updated the code to show more situations, and added a live demo. The only difference between the 2 expressions is when `value` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), which includes when value is `""` (empty string).